# Batch Job Transaction

Tags: batch-processing

Lets say there are 100 records in the database for a batch job, when batch job runs and pick up those 100 record and then start processing. During process if error occurs at 10th record then should I rollback all 9 records which are already been processed.

How can we design this scenario??? Your suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're asking *if* you should roll back successful records if an error occurs part-way through batch processing.

You want your DB updates to occur in transactions in a way that leaves database records consistent and legal (with respect to DB and business rules) after each transaction is committed or rolled back.

If each item in your list of 100 records can be processed and recorded individually, then I'd suggest using a flag of some sort (this could be a status field, as well) to indicate whether each record has been processed, then loop through the records to update each one.  If you encounter an error, note that somewhere (log file, exception, error table... your call) and move on.  When you're done, you'll have logged which records were successful and which failed.  You should then be able to go back and fix whatever caused the problem(s) on bad records and re-process the skipped records.

If all 100 of your records must succeed or fail together, then you'll need to wrap your updates in a transaction so they all succeed or fail as one.  This will work for dozens of records or (maybe) hundreds of records, but trying to scale up to thousands of records in the same transaction could create scalability problems (performance and contention issues), so you'd want a different solution for a pattern like that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in fact I have implemented that way only. I was checking with other experts how are they doing this kind of processing, and what is the best way to do that.... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is different transaction granularity possible.  Java (JTA) allows for multiple writes in a single commit.

1. Open transaction
2. write record
3. write record
4. write record
5. error
6. roll-back

Most databases also support transactions that can handle multiple rows or record writes.

This is very common.

Comment: is it good to rollback all records which were sucessful? In your example till point no 4 everything was fine and error occurs at point 5 now you want to roll back all successful records? What do you think if we commit all successful records and mark them executed by some flag and then batch job can pickup rest of them(point 5 onwards) next time. My question is basically what would be a best approach to design this scenario??? Should we make batch size and then roll back only failure batch or should we create savepoint and then rollback till savepoint ???

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SAVEPOINTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/savepoint.html) - they basically allow inner-transaction transactions.  So you can do quite a lot of work, make a SAVEPOINT, and do more work, only rolling back to the last save point.  If things go really wrong, you can just roll the entire transaction back.

Comment: Initially I tried SAVEPOINTS through Java (I don't have stored Procedure) but my situation doesn't allow it and also it needs more code and logic then maintaining in database table with a status column...Also saw a kind of performance issue there... thanks for your suggestion Mike...